# adding auth decorators to class based views

Tags: django, python-decorators, django-class-based-views

hi there im trying to apply auth decorators to my class based views but they seem not to work since when i view the template i do not get redirected to the default accounts/login/next? url

```
from .forms import TodoForm
from .models import Todo
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


# Create your views here.
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TodoListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'ToDo/todo_list.html'
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TodoDetailView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'ToDo/todo_detail.html'
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Todo, id=id_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use django auth decorators for CBV's(Class Based Views).You can use mixins to achieve this. For example, instead of login_required decorator you can use LoginRequiredMixin for a CBV as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

take a look at the docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin

Comment: alright let me check it out though got the decorator usage in class based views  from djangodocs